# investing with stash or acorn

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing

I recently came across these 2 apps (and a third, robinhood) which let you invest fairly small amounts of money. stash and acorns charge (at least) $1 per month and let you invest a sum as low as $5 per week.
Is it worth it ?
If i can only invest $5 per week I'm paying fairly close to 5% in fees. Will I be able to still make a profit or should I save this incredibly low amount in some other (hopefully free) account and invest it myself at some point ?

My situation: I have a total debt to annual income ratio of about 3, which includes a mortgage, car and some smaller debts. So most of my current "investments" are towards lowering debt (I keep maybe $100 cash on hand and make payments with anything over that). So $5 per week is possible, anything higher is probably better spent on lowering debt.

Comment: Are you saying your total debt is 3 years worth of gross income? Also, do you have no emergency fund other than that $100?

Comment: correct. I spend just about every dollar on bills and then just use credit cards to keep me afloat.

Comment: 5% fees, plus your highest interest rate is what you'd have to average in return to come out even with just paying extra towards the debt. Could make money, but unlikely, not worth it imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple. Put everything towards that debt, including even $5 a week, the compound interest that will be saved is probably significant.

Forget about investing at all before at least everything but your mortgage has been paid in full.

Paying down debt is an (almost) entirely risk-free investment.

Comment: Not almost - it _is_ risk free.  You _will_ get a return equal to the interest rate on the loan.

Answer (score 2):

> I spend just about every dollar on bills and then just use credit cards to keep me afloat.

It seems that you are trying to get your financial house in order, and that's good, but "investing" is far down the list.  (Except for 401(k) company match!)

First, you need to track **all** your spending, and find places to cut.  From partying to expensive auto insurance to gym memberships you don't use, everything must go under the microscope.

Then, build up a $1,000 emergency fund, and

Third hit the non-mortgage debt (CC first!).

After that, think about investing.

Comment: Assuming he is from the US.

Comment: @bjarkef AFAICT, none of the three services mentioned are available outside the US.  Thus, "Assuming he is from the US" is perfectly reasonable.